# Receiving data from server as json data but not able to parse the data in react

Tags: json, reactjs

I am receiving the data from server but not able to parse it. when i parse i am geeting an error as 
" Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()".

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';



class Premontessori extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      post:[]
    };

  }


componentDidMount(){
  axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
  .then(data =>  this.setState({post:data} )

);

    }


  render(){
    return(
    <div>
    {JSON.parse(this.state.post.data)}


</div>

    );
  }
}
export default Premontessori;
```

Comment: You are setting the property post to the payload received from the server so you should use {JSON.parse(this.state.post)} instead of {JSON.parse(this.state.post.data)}

Comment: if i do so i am getting an error as  Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: Can you please console.log(data) and provide what is coming back from the server?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/list')
.then(data =>  this.setState({post:data} )
```

...will set your state to `{post: ...}` where `...` is the value of `data`, which will presumably be a string or a parsed object tree, depending on whether `axios.get` automatically parses JSON when it receives it or not.

If it's a string, you need to parse it with `JSON.parse`. Then either use it directly:

```
.then(data =>  this.setState(JSON.parse(data) )
```

...or if it's really meant to be the value of `post`, then:

```
.then(data =>  this.setState({post: JSON.parse(data)} )
```

If it's *already* parsed, then I'm guessing it shouldn't be the value of a `post`, so:

```
.then(data =>  this.setState(data))
```